# How to add duration to Vue Toastify

Tags: vue.js, notifications, duration

I am using [Vue Toastify](https://github.com/nandi95/vue-toastify) for my project and everything is working except it doesn't disappear automatically. I have added `successDuration` and `errorDuration` but still it stays on the screen unless and until I click on it. This is what I have tried,

```
Vue.use(VueToastify,{
    position:"top-right",
    canTimeout:false,
    errorDuration:500,
    successDuration:500,
    alertInfoDuration:500,
    duration:500,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you've missed it out. You have to put `canTimeout: true`, and not `false`, then you can just specify the duration according to the `type`, which you've done with `successDuration` and `errorDuration` already.

```
Vue.use(VueToastify,{
    position:"top-right",
    canTimeout:true,
    errorDuration:500,
    successDuration:500,
    alertInfoDuration:500,
    duration:500,
});
```

EDIT: You can also just leave out the `canTimeout` param, since by default it's `true`

Comment: I have done exactly as you have suggested but it doesn't work.it stays there on screen until and unless I click on it.

Comment: Did you change the canTimeout variable?

Comment: Yes, I have changed exactly what you have explained but no change. I have to click on it in order to make it disappear.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: Alright.. Can you replicate this in a codesandbox.io for us then?

Answer (score 0):

Package writer here.
As per the above comment the `canTimeout` should be set to true or just left out.
Also there is no such global setting as `duration`. That can only be set on the status object